# Creating a Gmail instance with existing credentials using Gmail Java API

Tags: java, clojure, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, clojure-java-interop

**A little background:** I'm trying to do an API using Clojure that will ask for the user's permission to read his/her emails and then will execute queries to present ordered data.

For this I'm trying to use the Gmail Java API with an existing token.

Using the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.html) [available](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer), I was able to make a request to get a new token, but then I don't know how to create an instance of `com.google.api.services.gmail` using that previously retrieved token.

Here is how my relevant code looks like:

```
(ns linelos.gmail.core
  (:import (com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2 LocalServerReceiver)
           (com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2 GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
                                                     GoogleClientSecrets
                                                     GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder)
       (com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2 Credential BearerToken TokenResponse)
       (com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet GoogleNetHttpTransport)
       (com.google.api.client.http HttpTransport)
       (com.google.api.services.gmail Gmail Gmail$Builder)))

(def ^:private http-transport
  (GoogleNetHttpTransport/newTrustedTransport))

(def ^:private json-factory (JacksonFactory/getDefaultInstance))

(defn get-connection [access-token]
  (let [token-response (-> (TokenResponse.) (.setAccessToken access-token))
    credential     (-> (Credential. (BearerToken/authorizationHeaderAccessMethod))
                       (.setFromTokenResponse token-response))
    ; I'm stuck here
    gmail-builder  (Gmail$Builder. http-transport json-factory ???) 
    gmail          (-> gmail-builder
                       (.setApplicationName app-name)
                       .build)]
    gmail))
```

Am I missing something else, like a helper to create requests using a Token?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their [OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#credential):

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Plus plus = new Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("Google-PlusSample/1.0")
    .build();
```

The third argument to `Gmail$Builder` constructor expects an instance of `com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer` (or null). Their [`GoogleCredential`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential) class *implements* that interface. Have you tried passing `credential` as the third argument (where you have `???`)?

Something like this might work:

```
(defn get-connection [access-token]
  (let [token-response (-> (TokenResponse.) (.setAccessToken access-token))
        credential     (-> (Credential. (BearerToken/authorizationHeaderAccessMethod))
                           (.setFromTokenResponse token-response))]
    (-> (Gmail$Builder. http-transport json-factory credential)
        (.setApplicationName app-name)
        (.build))))
```

Comment: Yeah!, I replaced my `Credential` instance with `GoogleCredential` and it worked. Thank  you!